# Правильный синтаксический разбор или нет?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, члены-предложения

Нам необходимо реализовать стратегию экономического партнёрства и расширить сотрудничество в сфере торговли и инвестиций, научно-технических инноваций, зеленого и низкоуглеродного развития и в других областях.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, я правильно разобрала предложение? Очень не уверена насчет всего, что стоит после "сотрудничество".

- Нам (дополнение) необходимо реализовать (сказуемое) стратегию (дополнение) экономического (определение) партнёрства (дополнение) и расширить (2 однородное сказуемое) сотрудничество (дополнение) в сфере (обстоятельство) торговли и инвестиций (дополнение), научно-технических (определение) инноваций (дополнение), зеленого и низкоуглеродного (определение) развития (дополнение) и других (определение) областях (обстоятельство).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Нам необходимо реализовать** стратегию экономического партнёрства **и расширить** сотрудничество в сфере торговли и инвестиций, научно-технических инноваций, зеленого и низкоуглеродного развития и в других областях.*

Порядок разбора, как я думаю, должен быть связан со структурой предложения.

1. **Предложение** простое, односоставное безличное, осложнено однородными сказуемыми и однородными дополнениями.

**Грамматическая основа**: *необходимо реализовать и расширить*, сказуемое составное глагольное, связка выражена предикативным наречием "необходимо", инфинитивные части связаны однородными отношениями, для связи используется союз И.

Субъект действия обозначен дополнением "нам".

2. Каждое сказуемое имеет **прямое дополнение** в форме В.п.: реализовать (что) стратегию, расширить (что) сотрудничество.
3. **Стратегию** (чего) – (экономического) партнерства, дополнение.
4. **Сотрудничество** (в чем) – в сфере  и в (других) областях – однородные дополнения.
5. **В сфере** (чего)  – торговли и инвестиций, (научно-технических) инноваций, (зеленого и низкоуглеродного) развития – однородные дополнения.
6. Экономического, научно-технических, зеленого и низкоуглеродного, других – определения.

**Примечание.** Возможно (как вариант), что здесь есть неделимые словосочетания, так некоторые существительные (сфера, область, развитие) без дополнений и определений выражены неясно (но это уже детали из области семантики).

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!